# How to install Netbeans 8.0.2 on ubuntu 14.x

Tags: command-line, software-installation, 14.10, netbeans, sh

I have netbeans downloaded from the [netbeans.org](https://netbeans.org/downloads/) site.
This is the file name → `netbeans-8.0.2-linux.sh`
I dont know how to install it on ubuntu 14.10 
Is there any one can help me install netbeans on ubuntu?

Comment: .sh? *shudders*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open the `Terminal` and considering the file is in Downloads directory then do

> chmod +x ~/Downloads/netbeans-8.0.2-linux.sh

After that

> cd ~/Downloads && ./netbeans-8.0.2-linux.sh

And that will bring up the Installation Window.

To Uninstall run

> ./uninstall.sh

in the install directory

Comment: I am looking for command line installation that does not launch the installer GUI. Is this possible?

Comment: ./netbeans-8.0.2-linux.sh --silent

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I handled it, after reading this thread;
I tried first to check the file permissions, through the graphical interface, by opening

> 'home', 'download',

i.e. the location where I put netbeans-8.0.2-linux.sh;
seeing the button for changing the file to executable was unchecked, I checked it;
I opened a terminal, changed to the directory where netbeans was, and typed:

> 'netbeans-8.0.2-linux.sh'

only to be greeted by a 'command not found'...
so I went over the web to check the reason...
and found this thread;
by reading it, I have a better idea of what is going on;
so, I tried, as a last resort, to issue the command like that:

> sudo bash netbeans-8.0.2-linux.sh

...and it went on, smoothly, installing everything.
I just want to add that it didn't really need my password, strange enough;
but it looks it needed to be prefixed with 'bash', otherwise it didn't recognize it, even if the permissions were all there, I checked with 
'ls -l', and it was executable for all :user, groups, and others...
I wonder if I have something out of order, or simply configured in some special way, in my config files, maybe in the proc directory...
but now I have another problem:
I started a C project, just to try how netbeans worked, and it did open, create really, a project skeleton;
but it does not find the standard library headers, 'stdio.h' and s'tdlib.h'...

Because, now, this is a separate issue, I will not expand it here; I should start another thread on it.

Anyway, thank so much for the help found in this page :)

I am new to linux, and trying to learn it.
Any clarification would be very welcome.

Ubuntu 14.10 amd turion x2 64 advent 9515 2GB ram

Comment: Adding 'bash' to the command, really solved the "command not found" problem. I have no idea, why someone voted down this answer. It was useful for me!